# Random and negative numbers

Tags: c++, random, negative-number

I have to generate numbers in range **[-100; +2000]** in c++. How can I do this with rand if there is only positive numbers available? Are there any fast ways?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

generate a random number between 0 and 2100 then subtract 100.

A quick google search turned up a [decent looking article on using Rand().](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread1769.html)  It includes code examples for working with a specific range at the end of the article.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the C++ TR1 random functions to generate numbers in the desired distribution.

```
std::random_device rseed;
std::mt19937 rng(rseed());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(-100,2100);

std::cout << dist(rng) << '\n';
```

Comment: For those without TR1, boost::random is quite close.

Answer (score 8):

Generate a random number between 0 and 2100, and subtract 100.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int min = 999, max = -1;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < 100000; ++i )
    {
        int val = (rand()%2101)-100;
        if( val < min ) min = val;
        if( val > max ) max = val;
    }

}
```

Comment: This will not give an even distribution! Also, finding the minimum and maximum of 100000 such numbers is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Also if by chance `val` was `-100` every time, the resulting `max` would be wrong.  Ditto for minimum.

Comment: @Cornelius, @Ben:  Who cares?  It's just a demo.  If I had posted just `(rand()%2101)-100` that would have been better than a compilable, runnable sample?  Please.

Answer (score 3):

Can you generate a number from 0-2100 and subtract 100?

Answer (score 1):

In C++0x they will enhance this to provide better support for it with a standard library.

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#std-random

Answer (score 0):

Currently my C++ syntax is a little rusty, but you should write a function that takes two parameters: `size` and `offset`.

So you generate numbers with the given `size` as maximum value and afterwards add the (negative) offset to it.

The function would look like:

```
int GetRandom(int size, int offset = 0);
```

and would be called in your case with:

```
int myValue = GetRandom(2100, -100);
```