# how to get random number between 5 and -5 in c++

Tags: c++, random

i am trying to get random numbers using `rand % (5 -5)` and it gives division by zero error

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int A[20];
for (int i-=0 ;i<20;i++)
 A[i]= rand() % -5;

system("pause")
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question isn't exactly a duplicate, but see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20136256/7359094).

Comment: Did you check what values rand returns?

Comment: Also [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830663/) - possible duplicate

Comment: @ricco19 It's a shame all of those answers are so out dated. The only modern answer predates c++11 and uses tr1.

Comment: Not sure how you are getting a devision by zero error but `for (int i-0 ;i<20;i++)` is not correct.

Comment: `<random>` has facilities to avoid modulus

Comment: @NathanOliver that was a typo

Comment: i am trying  to get negative and positove random values between -5 and 5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random numbers uniformly over an entire range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288739/generate-random-numbers-uniformly-over-an-entire-range)

Comment: @KashifMehmood3314-FBASBSSEF1 If there is a typo in the question, please edit the question to remove the typo so it won't confuse future readers.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux already did

Comment: You now have `for (int i-=0 ;i<20;i++)` which still isn't correct.  Is that what you really have?

Answer (score 2):

Just use [std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

> Produces random integer values i, uniformly distributed on the closed interval [a, b]...

```
std::random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(-5, 5);
std::cout << dis(gen) << std::endl;
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/yJfncJ)

Answer (score 0):

`rand` returns :

> a pseudo-random integral value between ​0​ and RAND_MAX (0 and RAND_MAX included).

To get a value from the range [-5, .., 5] (inclusive) you have to calculate it from the range [0, .., RAND_MAX].

In the range [-5, .., 5] there are 11 values [-5, .., -1, 0, 1, .., 5].

Starting from (and including) 0, counting 11 values, the final number is 10.

To return values [0, .., 10] from the bigger range, *mod* can be used. But you need in the results a 10 so a *mod* 11 has to be used.

Now to get a value to a range [-5, .., 5] from a range [0, .., 10], you need to subtract 5.

```
const int val_from_rand = rand();
const int range_0_10 = val_from_rand % 11;
const int random_val = range_0_10 - 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the new random library

```
#include <random>

// Seed with a real random value, if available
std::random_device r;
std::default_random_engine e1(r()); 
// A random number between - 5 and 5
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(-5, 5);

int nextRandom()
{
    return uniform_dist(e1);
}
```

Which is called:

```
int r = nextRandom();
```

---

You can also create a generalized version:

```
template< int low, int high >
int nextRandom()
{
    static_assert( low < high, "low must be < high" );

    // Seed with a real random value, if available
    static std::random_device         r;
    static std::default_random_engine e1( r() );
    // A random number between low and high
    static std::uniform_int_distribution< int > uniform_dist( low, high );

    return uniform_dist( e1 );
}
```

Which is called:

```
int random = nextRandom< -5, 5 >();
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `;` after `system("pause")`.
Apart from that, you were not far from the solution.

However reading the the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) you see that `%5` would return numbers between 0 and 4, and `%-5` does not make any sense.

You can return numbers between 0 and 10 (10 included) and then scale it down by subtracting `-5`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[20];
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
        a[i] = (rand() % 11)-5; //use %10 if you do not want 5 as apossible outcome
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

That is the easiest way and closest to your solution.

Please do not use capital letters for variables unless they are constant.

Answer (score -6):

You can try this code

`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
   int number = 0;

   srand(time(NULL));

   do
   {
      number = rand();
   }while(number > 5);

return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: I don't know who up-voted this, but it shouldn't be. This answer won't do what the question asks and attempts to do so in an incredibly inefficient way.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That up vote has me flabbergasted as well.  This is about the worst way you could ask to get a random number, and it doesn't even get it for the correct range. :(

Comment: i am trying to get negative and positive values between 5 and -5

Comment: @Frank No, it gets a number between 0 and 5.  `INT_MIN` is a negative number.